# What does this regex mean in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python and I am trying to understand this regex:

```
pattern = r"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]{2,200}$"
```

What does `%+-` and `.-` mean?

Comment: They are just matching those characters / symbols .

Comment: `[%+-]` match either `% `  `+ ` or  `-`

Comment: `%` and `+` have no special meaning inside `[ ]`, so they are just characters to be matched. `-` does have special mean, defining a range of characters, as you see wit e.g. `A-Z`, but if it appears first `[-xxx]` or last `[xxx-]`, then it is treated as just a character to match. The same could be done with escaping `[xx\-xx]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[%+-]` means match either `%`, `+`, or `-`.  Why we don't use escape character `\` ? because they are in side `[]`

`[.-]` means match either `.` or `-` Why we don't use escape character `\` ? because they are in side `[]`,

Furthermore  `-` can also mean a range if between a range characters like `[A-Z]` or `[0-9]` in other case it is treated literally as in `[AZ-]`.

Comment: Incomplete answer, since you don't explain difference between `[A-Z]` and `[AZ-]`

Answer (score 4):

They're inside `[]`, so they're part of a character class. It matches those literal characters.

A `-` is a special character inside a character class only if it appears somewhere in the middle of the class (as in `A-Z`, where it means the whole range of characters from A to Z). If it appears at the beginning or end of the class, it means a literal `-`.

(That regular expression looks like it matches an email address, for a certain definition of "email address.")

Comment: Incomplete answer, since you don't explain difference between `[A-Z]` and `[AZ-]`

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, I updated my answer.